# Unwanted HTML output from try {} section

Tags: html, asp.net, exception, razor

The following ASP.NET code:

```
@try
    { 
      int a = 1; 
      int b = 0;
      if (a > b) 
      {
         <b>a is greater than b!</b>
      }
      a = a / b;
    }
catch
    {
      <b>there was an error</b>
    }
```

renders as

```
 <b>a is greater than b!</b>
 <b>there was an error</b>
```

I want to print only the error message in case of an exception. Help please?

Comment: Move the `a = a/b` above the `if`

Answer (score 1):

the rendered text is correct. First it renders the first line, afterwards you do a / b, and b is equal to 0. Division by 0 results into an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is not pretty but it answers the question as asked. It was tested and works.

```
    @{HtmlString  myOutput = null;
        try
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 0;
            if (a > b)
            {
                myOutput = new HtmlString("<b>a is greater than b!</b>"); 
            }
            a = a / b;
        }
        catch
        {
            myOutput = new HtmlString("<b>there was an error</b>");
        }
        finally
        {
            @myOutput
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use razor, but here's a guess as a solution:

```
@try
    { 
      int a = 1; 
      int b = 0;
      if (a > b) 
      {
         a = a / b;
         <b>a is greater than b!</b>
      }
    }
catch
    {
      <b>there was an error</b>
    }
```

Basically, the trick is to output your message after performing the division, so that the exception occurs before the output happens.